# Is there a special title for someone who achieves "Tsaheylu" with a thanator?

Tags: aliens, avatar

In the Avatar (movie), when Jake was able to establish [Tsaheylu](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Tsaheylu) with Toruk he was recognized as Toruk Makto. So when Nitiri achieves [Tsaheylu](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Tsaheylu) with the thanator, had it been that creature was not killed by Col. Quaritch would there had been a special title for her?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Avatar wiki, the Na'Vi name for a thanator is a palulukan (meaning "dry mouth bringer of fear"). If the structure of the language is consistent, then Neytiri would have been called a 'Palulukan Makto', or 'Rider of the Dry Mouth Bringer of Fear'.

The movie does not state whether there was any mythology or unusual status associated with those who may become Palulukan Makto. But based on the way the creature is portrayed, I would guess that it is rare for Na'Vi to establish Tsaheylu with them; perhaps as rare as it would be to become Toruk Makto, as the thanators appear willing to hunt and eat Na'Vi, whereas the Toruk would be unlikely to notice a Na'Vi unless it was hunting the banshee that the Na'vi was riding.